# Simple CSS alignment: works in Firefox but not in Safari or Chrome?

Tags: html, css, frontend

http://test.heyscout.com/video.html

I think the CSS code looks right. 
When I open it in Firefox, it opens up fine and the videos line up. But if I open it up in Chrome or Safari, it gets all misaligned. Any ideas why?

I feel like it may have to do with setting display: inline-block correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `inline-block` elements are white-space dependent ..

If you reduce the `#space2` div width to `49%` they are aligned on safari & chrome

The white space in your mark-up is causing there to be a little gap between the two divs even though there widths both add up to 100%. If you get rid of the white-space and compress that part of your HTML giving both widths 50% works fine .. I just tested it in chrome ver 25.0.1364.97.

Comment: also chrome 25 has a bug with inline-block, so that could add to the confusion

Answer (score 0):

```
#space1 {
width: 50%;
height: 350px;
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}

#space2 {
width: 50%;
height: 350px;
/* float: right; */
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```